# How to send document or images in group using plain javascript pusher chatkit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher, pusher-js, chatkit

I have my chat application ready using plain javascript and pusher Chatkit. Now I want to send files or images in chat in the message. how to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatkit has `sendMultipartMessage` method which allows complex messages(attachment,URL etc). 
Example from the [docs](https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/reference/javascript#sending-a-message) -

```
currentUser.sendMultipartMessage({
  roomId: myRoom.id,
  parts: [
    { type: "text/plain", content: "" },
    {
      type: "image/gif",
      url: "https://gfycat.com/failingforkedheterodontosaurus",
    },
    {
      file: document.querySelector("#attach").files[0],
      customData: { metadata: 42 },
    }
  ],
});
```

One tutorial that uses multipartMessaging - https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-attachments-chatroom#migrate-to-multipart-messages